# What consequences of the global climate change are expected in the next 50 years?

Tags: climate-change, temperature

It is known, that due to global warming, the average temperature on Earth over the past 100 years has increased by 1.2 degrees. At the same time, I heard that earlier the temperature of the Earth was 7 degrees higher than the current one.

I do not deny the danger of global warming, because I have seen the information that not only the concentration of CO2 is important, but also the rate of its change: with the current rate, the ecosystems do not have enough time to react, and positive feedback can work now (the ocean, heating up, releases water vapor, which is also a greenhouse gas). But I would like to see these points explained in more detail.

https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.1910114117

Here it is written that in the cause of "business-as-usual climate scenario" (this means the worst scenario,  if no mitigating action were taken?), on the territories, where 3.5 billion people are living now, the mean annual temperature (MAT) will be like in Sahara now (and the human life there will be impossible). These territories include half of Africa, half of Arabian Peninsula, most of India, most of Southeast Asia, a part of Australia and a half os South America. How probable is this scenario considered? And what is the scenarion if the states will reduce the CO2 emission as planned now?

Comment: It strongly depends in advances in clean energy technology and political things as US election results in the next 50 years